# Compare 2 objects to create a new array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an two elements fruits and crates

`fruits` is an array containing a list of different fruits like:

```
["apple","orange","mango","pear"]
```

`crates` is an array of objects which contains fruits in it like :

```
[{id:1,fruit_name: "apple"},{id:2, fruit_name: "pear"}]
```

I want to create a new array of objects based following conditions:
- check if an entity from fruits array is present in any array of crates.

If present then the final object should have the `fruit_name` property along with another property called `tested` set to `true`.
    If not present then `tested` should be `false`;

considering above scenario the final output should be as follows:

```
[
    {fruit_name: "apple", tested: true},
    {fruit_name: "orange", tested: false},
    {fruit_name: "mango", tested: false},
    {fruit_name: "pear", tested: true},
]
```

What I have tried is as follows:

```
fruits.forEach(x => {
                        crates.filter((y) => {
                            let temp;
                            if (x == y.fruit_name) {
                                temp = {
                                    fruit: x,
                                    tested: true
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                temp = {
                                    time: x,
                                    tested: false
                                }
                            }
                            testedCrates.push(temp);
                        })
                    })
```

the problem with this is, it is returning each fruit two times with both values for tested property.

the output i get is as follows:

```
[
    {fruit: "apple", tested: true}, 
    {time: "apple", tested: false},
    {time: "orange", tested: false},
    {time: "orange", tested: false},
    {time: "mango", tested: false},
    {time: "mango", tested: false},
    {time: "pear", tested: false},
    {time: "pear", tested: false}
]
```

kindly suggest some fix for this. 
Additionally if there is a better way of doing this with es6 approach would be helpful.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#map` and `array#some` to check if a fruit exist in the `crates`.

```js
var fruits = ["apple","orange","mango","pear"],
crates = [{id:1,fruit_name: "apple"},{id:2, fruit_name: "pear"}];

var result = fruits.map(fruit => {
  var tested = crates.some(({fruit_name}) => fruit_name === fruit);
  return {'fruit_name' : fruit, tested};
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of fruits that exist in the crates, then [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the fruits array to the wanted form:

```js
const fruits = ["apple","orange","mango","pear"]
const crates = [{id:1,fruit_name: "apple"},{id:2, fruit_name: "pear"}];
const cratesSet = new Set(crates.map(({ fruit_name }) => fruit_name));

const result = fruits.map((fruit_name) => ({
  fruit_name,
  tests: cratesSet.has(fruit_name)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for `crates` and iterate `fruits` for a new array while checking the set.

```js
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "mango", "pear"],
    crates = [{ id: 1, fruit_name: "apple" }, { id: 2, fruit_name: "pear" }],
    cSet = new Set(crates.map(({ fruit_name }) => fruit_name)),
    result = fruits.map(fruit_name => ({ fruit_name, tested: cSet.has(fruit_name) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fruits.map(fruit => ({
  fruit_name: fruit,
  tested: crates.some(crate => crate.fruit === fruit),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits.map(fruit=>({
    fruit_name: fruit,
    tested: crates.some(x=>x.fruit_name === fruit)
}))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits.forEach(x => {
    let temp = { fruit: x, tested: false }

    crates.filter(y => {
        if (x === y.fruit_name)
            temp = { fruit: x, tested: true }
})
testedCrates.push(temp);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.